# JS Appended Array in FomData not accessable in Django backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In a django template i have this js script:

```
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        formData.append('taglist', JSON.stringify(selectedTagIds));

        console.log(JSON.parse(formData.get('taglist')))
        console.log(formData.get('title_raw'))
        
        form.submit()
```

`selectedTagIds` is an array. The console logs it correctly. After submitting I can access every standard form field in the django view but not the "`taglist`". The field doesn't exist in the form. When I try to print it i get "`None`". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `formData` isn't sent. `form.submit()` submits the HTML form. What makes your think there is a binding between the HTML form and a formData? Please read the documentation [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to add the stringified array in the value of a hidden input in the form to submit.

```
const additionalInput = document.createElement("input")
additionalInput.value = JSON.stringify(selectedTagIds)
additionalInput.name = 'taglist'
additionalInput.type = 'hidden'
form.append(additionalInput)

form.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a member in your form class, you can access it by calling

```
j = json.loads(request.POST["taglist"])
```

Comment: I've tried this before but I still got None.